# error in Python calling Amazon data exchange when simulating CLI call

Tags: python, amazon-web-services

I am trying to use python to simulate a call which I can make to amazon data exchange via CLI. This is an api call to ADX which then in turn calls my API (as part of a published product) and in which my API then parses a csv in an S3 bucket and returns json.
The CLI call is like this:

```
C:\Program Files\Amazon\AWSCLIV2\awscli>


 aws dataexchange send-api-asset \
 --data-set-id 4114ba1ff444gg772f3054bec1b8db \
 --revision-id c419b4d555566hhhd400094090c \ 
 --asset-id e74c3dddd555ttt77a9bde41a5b3 \
 --method GET \
 --request-headers "x-api-key=ln9JHVifake_keyK71h49L99D2EpGS" \
 --query-string-parameters fmt=csv
```

I get a good response with data.
Now, in python, attempting to simulate this, I need to provide credentials as well.
This is my python code:

```
import json
import base64
import zlib
import gzip
import codecs
import boto3
import requests
import urllib.parse


CLIENT = boto3.client('dataexchange', region_name='us-east-1', aws_access_key_id='ZA5Qsome_keyFNRDRW2V',
                      aws_secret_access_key='4877KbJVpsome_keyOZAA21pA5h3g5k')

csv = 'csv'
json_value = 'json'

DATA_SET_ID = '4114b445678888bec1b8db'
REVISION_ID = 'c419b4565777b6d400094090c'
ASSET_ID = 'e74c36ffr5566y77a9bde41a5b3'
METHOD = 'GET'
Headers = {'x-api-key': 'ln9JHVibfake_keyfr456L99D2EpGS', 'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip,deflate', 'Accept': '*/*'}

QueryStringParameters = {'fmt': csv}

response = CLIENT.send_api_asset(
    DataSetId=DATA_SET_ID,
    RevisionId=REVISION_ID,
    AssetId=ASSET_ID,
    Method=METHOD,
    QueryStringParameters=QueryStringParameters,
    RequestHeaders=Headers
    )

if response.headers.get("content-encoding") == "gzip":
    compressed_data = response.content
    encoded = base64.b64encode(compressed_data).decode('utf-8')
    response_text = encoded("ascii")
else:
    response_text = response.text

print(response_text)
```

I am getting an error like this:

```
if response.headers.get("content-encoding") == "gzip":
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'headers'
```